# rsyslog use different templates to store logs

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I am using `rsyslog` to handle the logs that my program creates. I have used a template to customize the logs format. My doubts are:

- If I create a template, every program that use that `rsyslog.conf` file, will store its logs using that template?
- How can I create 2 templates so that different program functions store their logs in different format?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `rsyslog` logs based on their program names.

Create a new file, /etc/rsyslog.d/01-programone.conf with these lines,

```
if $programname == 'programone' then /var/log/programone.log
```